# how to resolve race conditions in webdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I have an app that uses a mixture of angular and asp.net. My issue is that the home page is redirected by setting window.location and then the required data and page is requested form the server.

Previously this was not the case and all routing was done via the angular app. However due to requirements the applications routing had to be changed to what it is now.

Now because the application requires a server side request/response (I believe) this is causing a race condition in my tests as I only receive the expected result once in every 5 tests.

At present I am not able to provide code to explain my situation. However, I will be albe to provide some code in a edit later today.

The only code I can provide for now would be the test that is being run. Although I do not believe this would help without the code running the application.

Comment: why dont you aks your answer after  you have an opportunity to post also you code?

Answer (score 0):

Recent frameworks have this feature where it sets the document.readState of browser to complete and the content is loaded afterwards. Due to this the test may fails as we will be expecting an element to be present.

For such conditions you have to use explicit wait for the element to be present for which you want to take an action after the page is loaded or changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how we wait for elements in our project (The application is also angularjs, we use Java for webdriver):

In our Webdriver implementation we added:

```
private WebDriverWait iWait(int timeoutInSeconds) {
    return new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
}
```

we want to wait for an element to be visible ("Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0"):

```
public void waitForElementToAppear(By by, int timeoutInSeconds) {
    iWait(timeoutInSeconds).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
}
```

the ExpectedConditions class provides many other out of the box condition, here are some:

- elementToBeClickable
- textToBePresentInElement
- titleContains
- elementSelectionStateToBe

for more, please look at the [ExpectedConditions Javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

if you need to create your own conditions, you can use ExoectedCondition (no 's') class
[ExpectedCondition Javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html)